# Application Blocked. Your security settings have blocked an application from running with an out-of-date or expired version of java

Tags: java, oracle, formularios

Me aparece este código de error cuanto intento ejecutar Oracle Forms en local en Internet Explorer :

```
Application Blocked. Your security settings have blocked an application from running with an out-of-date or expired version of java
```

Necesito otra solución que no sea actualizar el java, ya que es el que tengo que usar en el trabajo(ya se que tiene agujeros de seguridad muy grandes)

Comment: El problema es que el propio plugin de Java para Internet Explorer va a comprobar vía online si la versión está obsoleta (y por tanto no es segura). La única solución es actualizar la versión de Java, al menos hasta la revisión más reciente.

Comment: Tiene que haber otra solución, ya que a mi compañero le funciona correctamente con la misma versíón, tanto de Oracle Forms como de Internet Explorer

Comment: El mensaje dice `Your security settings ...` comprueba si puedes modificar esa configuración de seguridad en el panel de configuración de Java.